# cannot access flash function through javascript and XUL

Tags: javascript, flash, embed, xul, typeerror

I'm currently trying to make a firefox extension and I cannot figure out what is my error.

Praticaly, I embed a flash application in my xul code in order to have access to some flash functions in the javascript code.

Thought this kind of stuff works with a basic html page, I am facing the "TypeError : [the flash function] is not a function" error when I try to use a flash function from my xul code.

I'm somehow a beginner in xul coding: would someone highlight my mistakes, I would be really grateful.

Here is my xul file:

```xml
<overlay id="extension-overlay" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script src="overlay.js"/>
    <window id="main-window">
        <toolbaritem id="extension-fontlist_container" persist="width">
            <html:embed hidden="true" wmode="transparent" id="extension-fontlist" height="1px" width="1px" menu="false" src="FontList.swf" allowscriptaccess='always' align='center' flashvars="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        </toolbaritem>

        <statusbar id="status-bar">
            <statusbarpanel id="my-panel" label="&gathering;" onload="Extension.onMenuItemCommand(event);"/>
        </statusbar>
    </window>
</overlay>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```javascript
var Extension = {
    onMenuItemCommand: function() {
        var flashObj = document.getElementById("extension-fontlist");
        var fontArr=flashObj.getDeviceFonts();
        var font="";
        for (var key in fontArr){
            var fontName = fontArr[key];
            fontName = fontName.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
            font+=fontName+"; ";
        }
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to unwrap the flash object

```
var flashObj = XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(document.getElementById("extension-fontlist"));
```

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry for the late reply.Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, it didn't work... I got exactly the same error. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't work ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tested [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) and flash-javascript communication works as expected.